# Renumbering vertices in a graph in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am generating a network using the code below for `N=2`. However, I would like to renumber the vertices starting from `0` and not `1`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import networkx as nx
N=2

def pos():
    x, y = 1, N + 3 - 1
    for _ in range(2 * N * (N + 1)):
        yield (x, y)
        y -= (x + 2) // (N + 3)
        x = (x + 2) % (N + 3)

G = nx.Graph()
it_pos = pos()
for u in range(2 * N * (N + 1)):
    G.add_node(u+1, pos=next(it_pos))
    if u % (2 * N + 1) < N:
        for v in (u - 2 * N - 1, u - N - 1, u - N):
            if G.has_node(v + 1):
                G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)
    elif u % (2 * N + 1) == N:
        G.add_edge(u + 1, u - N + 1)
    elif u % (2 * N + 1) < 2 * N:
        for v in (u - 1, u - N - 1, u - N):
            G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)
    else:
        for v in (u - 1, u - N - 1):
            G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)

nx.draw(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
```

The current output is

[image]

The expected output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `nx.relabel_nodes` function (doc [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html#networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes)):

```
import networkx as nx
N=2

def pos():
    x, y = 1, N + 3 - 1
    for _ in range(2 * N * (N + 1)):
        yield (x, y)
        y -= (x + 2) // (N + 3)
        x = (x + 2) % (N + 3)

G = nx.Graph()
it_pos = pos()
for u in range(2 * N * (N + 1)):
    G.add_node(u+1, pos=next(it_pos))
    if u % (2 * N + 1) < N:
        for v in (u - 2 * N - 1, u - N - 1, u - N):
            if G.has_node(v + 1):
                G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)
    elif u % (2 * N + 1) == N:
        G.add_edge(u + 1, u - N + 1)
    elif u % (2 * N + 1) < 2 * N:
        for v in (u - 1, u - N - 1, u - N):
            G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)
    else:
        for v in (u - 1, u - N - 1):
            G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)

#relabelling nodes
G=nx.relabel_nodes(G,{i:i-1 for i in range(1,G.number_of_nodes()+1)},copy=False)

nx.draw(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
```

[image]